# Can I cash out my 403b any time after I leave the country?

Tags: united-states, non-resident, pension, moving, 403b

I'm British and will be moving back to the UK soon. My current employer pays into my 403b. When I leave I'll probably take it with me, although I accept this will come with penalties and taxes. I was thinking of taking it out the year after I leave so it doesn't get added to this year's income and tax bill, but am I able to do that? Or do I have to take it when my employment ends?

Comment: You'll need to check the plan rules

Answer (score 1):

Many plans have a minimum amount that you are required to maintain in order to keep money in the plan.  Below that amount, they can force you out and mail you a check or roll you into a safe harbor IRA and wash their hands of you.  If you're above that amount, they can't force you out until it dips below the limit or you get old enough to hit the required minimum distributions in your 70s.  Generally the limit is $5,000.